# share only theme variables of my sass/scss variables

Tags: sass, theming

---

I need to share some sass/scss variables for several webcomponents. For that we created a very usefull "_variables.scss" on an npm package. 
The thing is we use two ground of colors :

- what i would call "real colors" : (`$blue-unicorn`,
  `$pink-butterfly`)
- and theme colors : (`$brand-color`, `$secondary-color`)

and **we only want to share the theme color variables**

the theme colors are made this way : `$brand-color : $blue-unicorn;`
if the DA suddenly decide to use a `$grey-grave` and a `$black-shadow` colors we will just have to update the npm package and won't have to change variable names all other the code on the various web components. 
*If you wanna know more about this usage you can take a look on this article about palette colors and theme colors http://blog.magmalabs.io/2018/04/17/nice-way-handle-sass-color-variables.html.*

the original file with our variables.scss is this one :

```
@import 'variables/_colors';

$brand-color: $blue-unicorn;
$secondary-color: $pink-butterfly;
```

and we use `scss-bundle` npm package to obtain that for clients of our package

```
$blue-unicorn: #0081EB;
$pink-butterfly: #F62880;

$brand-color: $blue-unicorn;
$secondary-color: $pink-butterfly;
```

we don't want users to access the real colors

### what would be the proper way to obtain that ?

```
$brand-color: #0081EB;
$secondary-color: #F62880;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your users should use the scss files then the only option is the new module system that is as of now only supported by the Dart Sass compiler. You'd nee to replace the `@import` directives with `@use` and prefix all private variables with a `-` as this makes them private and they won't be shared.

Again, this is only supported in Dart Sass of now.

For more infos see the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use).

Comment: well ! looks perfect to me. I will test that asap and give you my feedback.

Comment: I couldn't make it work on my case. cause if I use `@use 'variables/_colors'`; the way you suggested my $brand-color can't access $blue-unicorn. Please let me know if i miss something.